# SQL query performance, unexpected results - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-optimization, resultset

I wrote a simple loop code in SQL Server to measure performance of my SQL query. The measurement times I get from that code are in 95% of times as expected, very similar to each other, but sometimes the time can be 3-4 times higher than the normal one. There is no other process obtaining database at the same time.

```
declare @tTOTAL int = 0
declare @i integer = 0
declare @itrs integer = 100

while @i < @itrs
  begin

  CHECKPOINT;  DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;  DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
   declare @t0 datetime2 = GETDATE()

     // Here goes the query to measure its performance
     SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Comments] AS [c] WHERE [c].[Score] > 100

   declare @t1 datetime2 = GETDATE()

   set @tTotal = DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@t0,@t1)
   select @tTotal as TimeT
   set @i = @i + 1

  end
```

If that is not the perfect way to measure query performance do you recommend any tool or way to do simple measurements as I want to do? (I need to get result of every single measurement, not only averages ...)

Comment: Query store can track the various metrics, aggregated over a unit of time (default 1 hour, but you can make it 5 or 1 min).  Your other choice is XEvents to dump particular events on query performance.  There can be various reasons for what you see, such as autostats.  Hard to see w/o table schema (is it a btree? columnstore? heap?)

Comment: Try use `SYSDATETIME()` rather than `GETDATE()`

Comment: You will have a hard time interpreting the results of this test even if you can figure out how to eliminate the anomalously high times. Repeating the same query on the same data multiple times basically tests the software's ability to satisfy a query from table data cached in the server machine's RAM. Under a real-world workload, you'll get stunningly different results than from your controlled example.  With respect, your experiment probably won't give you actionable results.